# Why does `math.ldexp` raise OverflowError for exponent>1024, but not for exponent<-1073?

Tags: python, ieee-754

`math.ldexp(0.5, 1025)` results in `OverflowError`.  Numpy's equivalent function returns `inf`.  On the other end, however, `math.ldexp(0.5, -1074)` does not raise an exception, but rather returns `0.0`, as illustrated below:

```
In [275]: math.ldexp(0.5, 1024)
Out[275]: 8.98846567431158e+307

In [276]: math.ldexp(0.5, 1025)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-276-ce1573e0249b> in <module>()
----> 1 math.ldexp(0.5, 1025)

OverflowError: math range error

In [277]: math.ldexp(0.5, -1073)
Out[277]: 5e-324

In [278]: math.ldexp(0.5, -1074)
Out[278]: 0.0
```

Why does Python raiso an `OverflowError` when the exponent is too large, but not when it is too small?  Is there a valid reason, or should this be considered a bug?

Comment: Floating point is an inexact representation.  `0.0` is the closest inexact representation for `math.ldexp(0.5, -1074)`.  There is no corresponding floating point representation for `math.ldexp(0.5, 1025)`.

Comment: A too small exponent is *underflow*, not *overflow*.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Floating point and `math.ldexp(a, b)` are exact representations for any number that can be written as `a*2**b`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IEEE floating point arithmetic is known to have some degree of imprecision.  0.0 is a value which is very close to `math.ldexp(0.5, -1074)`.  However, there is no valid way of expressing a value that is close to `math.ldexp(0.5, 1025)`, so I would assume that's why it raises an Exception.

Comment: It could return inf.  That's what you get if you do 2**1023 * 2.0.  It is what I expected ldexp to do, until I found out it didn't.